# Mac Ventura fails to find compilers

Tags: macos-ventura

Since I upgraded to OSX Ventura when I try to compile I get the message:
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

The same occurs when trying to build Ada programs with Visual Studio Code:

```
   [Ada]          hello_world.adb
gcc: error trying to exec 'gnat1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

gnat1 is available.

```
sudo find /opt -name "cc1"           
Password:
/opt/gnat-ce-2021/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/10.3.1/cc1
/opt/GNAT/2019/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.3.1/cc1
/opt/gcc-11.1.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/11.1.0/cc1
```

Similarly for gnat1

My Path includes /opt/gnat-ce-2021/bin
which worked under previous versions of Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xcode (or the Command Line Tools) are you using? I have the CLTs,

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 14.1.0.0.1.1666437224
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1667592295
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

You really need 14.1.

Is there something wrong with the permissions on `gnat1`, `cc1`? on this M1 mini I have

```
$ ls -l /opt/gnat-ce-2021/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/10.3.1/cc1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  35799072 14 Jun  2021 /opt/gnat-ce-2021/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/10.3.1/cc1
```

and no problems of the sort you're getting; BUT BUT there are all sorts of problems with earlier GCCs as supplied by myself or AdaCore, you need to define SDKROOT,

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
```

and then

```
$ /opt/gnat-ce-2021/bin/gcc hello.c -I$SDKROOT/usr/include -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib
```

If you were to try GCC 12.1, you'd get

```
$ /opt/gcc-12.1.0/bin/gcc hello.c
<built-in>: error: unknown value '13.0.0' of '-mmacosx-version-min'
```

... you need GCC 12.2 which no longer has the arbitrary upper limit on the OS major version.

---

You should be able to download the Alire toolkit compiler `gnat-x86_64-darwin-12.2.0-1.tar.gz` from [here](https://github.com/alire-project/GNAT-FSF-builds/releases/tag/gnat-12.2.0-1).

*Strongly* recommend to do this before unpacking:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine gnat-x86_64-darwin-12.2.0-1.tar.gz
```

Comment: I have XCode 14.1 and its Command Line Tools.
I discovered that I had the Brew version of GCC 12.2 but its aliases in usr/local/bin are all gcc-12 etc so I set aliases in my .profile as gcc to each one.

Comment: Now a simple C file compiles and runs.
I did try building GCC 12.2 myself but ran into a problem, then discovered that I had the Brew version so decided to try that.
I'm still have trouble with gnat1 however.
I've checked that its permissions are all OK.

Comment: I'm now having trouble finding a suitable GNAT to install.

Comment: Roger@Rogers-Mac-mini ~ % gcc --version
gcc-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Trying to build alire but the gnat1 problem stopped that.

Comment: Homebrew’s GCC doesn’t support Ada, dammit

Comment: I added a note on downloading a suitable (I hope :-) compiler at the end of the answer.

Comment: I've installed gnat-x86_64-darwin-12.2.0-1 successfully.
I seem to have had some success today but still not quite there.
Your help is greatly appreciated.